# Как скомпилировать .cs (C# source code) файл в .exe программу НЕ с помощью Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, компиляция

Я получил исходный код файла игры в формате .cs используя ILSpy, отредактировал его и теперь хочу протестировать, но не знаю как/используя что его скомпилировать обратно в .exe. Приму любой вариант КРОМЕ Visual Studio.

Comment: а почему не VS?

Comment: [Построение из командной строки с помощью csc.exe](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/command-line-building-with-csc-exe)

Comment: @codename0082016, потому что там целый solution нужен?

Answer (score 7):

Варианты:

1 [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)

2 [MonoDevelop](https://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj_1YyM5tDUAhVGIlAKHejwA5gQFggmMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.monodevelop.com%2F&usg=AFQjCNF_atKHZLCOPhmpjMJJ9LxWiaJ6fQ)

3 [Построение из командной строки с помощью csc.exe](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/command-line-building-with-csc-exe)

Примеры командных строк для компилятора C#

Компиляция File.cs и создание File.exe:

```
csc File.cs
```

Компиляция File.cs и создание File.dll:

```
csc /target:library File.cs
```

Компиляция File.cs и создание My.exe:

```
csc /out:My.exe File.cs
```

Компиляция всех файлов C# в текущем каталоге с включенными оптимизациями и определение символа DEBUG. Выводится файл File2.exe:

```
csc /define:DEBUG /optimize /out:File2.exe *.cs
```

Компиляция всех файлов C# в текущем каталоге с созданием отладочной версии File2.dll. Логотипы и предупреждения не отображаются:

```
csc /target:library /out:File2.dll /warn:0 /nologo /debug *.cs
```

Компиляция всех файлов C# в текущем каталоге в файл Something.xyz (библиотеку DLL):

```
csc /target:library /out:Something.xyz *.cs
```

Comment: Можно прописать маленький "батничек" и передавать ему аргументы, если операцию необходимо делать много раз

Answer (score -2):

[ссылка на stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18286855/how-can-i-compile-and-run-c-sharp-program-without-using-visual-studio)

If you have the .NET v4 installed (so if you have a newer windows or if you apply the windows updates)

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe nomefile.cs
```

or

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe nomefile.sln
```

or

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe nomefile.csproj
```

It's highly probable that if you have .NET installed, the %FrameworkDir% variable is set, so:

```
%FrameworkDir%\v4.0.30319\csc.exe ...

%FrameworkDir%\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe ...
```

Comment: Ответы как и вопросы, так же должны быть на русском